# activatedBackgoundIndicator lost due to reload

Tags: android, gridview, universal-image-loader, multichoiceitems

I use a GridView and [Universal Image Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) (UIL) to display a couple images. I've also implemented the example for *Selection* given in http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#CAB (*Enabling batch contextual actions in a ListView or GridView*). 
The Contextual Action Bar gets displayed well and I can update the title etc. but the *activatedBackgroundIndicator* gets lost.

When I select an item via longpress the item is initally highlighted. Then the whole GridView reloads and the indicator is lost. Every other item I add to the selection will also not be highlighted. I've no idea #1 why my gallery reloads or #2 why the indicator isn't shown.

Any ideas? Here's part of my code (which is pretty much the stub from examples):

**Gallery Fragment:**

```
grid.setLongClickable(true);
grid.setChoiceMode(AbsListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL);
grid.setMultiChoiceModeListener(new AbsListView.MultiChoiceModeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemCheckedStateChanged(ActionMode actionMode, int position, long id, boolean checked) {
        actionMode.setTitle(""+grid.getCheckedItemCount());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode actionMode, Menu menu) {
        actionMode.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.image_detail, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode actionMode, Menu menu) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode actionMode, MenuItem menuItem) {
        switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
            default:
                return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode actionMode) {

    }
});
```

**Grid Item's XML:**

```
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="120dip"
    android:background="?android:attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator"
    >

    <ImageView ...
```

**Adapter**

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    ...
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ...
        ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(...);
    }
}
```

The gallery also reloads when I call *ActionMode.finish()* or dismiss the *CAB*.

---

//edit: When I remove the call to UIL's displayImage() I can select items just fine (i. e. see the selection - selection itself does work either ways). But when the CAB is drawn or removed the whole thing reloads and the selection indicator vanishes.
Aside from the above code my Gallery Fragment looks pretty much like [this](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader/blob/master/sample/src/com/nostra13/universalimageloader/sample/fragment/ImageGridFragment.java)

//edit2: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11731857/android-persistant-gridview-selector-on-cab) did not fix it (as I already have it in my code).

Comment: I guess the problem is that the loaded image is placed above the background and thus the inidcator ain't visible. I'll try w/ setting some custom border or something like that ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually everything works fine but since the ImageView that's loaded fills the whole area it simply overlays the background indicator.

I "fixed" that by adding another *Layout* to my GridView items that acts as a selection indicator. Within `onItemCheckedStateChanged()` I set the visibility according to `checked`.

I hope this answer will help anyone who's just as stu*** as I was :)

Answer (score 0):

Your class representing list item needs a field that will indicate that item is checked:

```
 boolean checked;

 public void setChecked(boolean checked) {
   this.checked = checked;
 }

 public booelan isChecked() {
   return this.checked;
 }
```

Then update CAB callbacks like this:

```
@Override
public void onItemCheckedStateChanged(ActionMode actionMode, int position, long id, boolean checked) {
     actionMode.setTitle(""+grid.getCheckedItemCount());       
    ((YourItemType)yourGridAdapter.getItemAtPosition(position)).setChecked(checked);
     yourGridAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode actionMode, Menu menu) {
    actionMode.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.image_detail, menu);
    yourGridAdapter.setSelectionMode(true);
    yourGridAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode actionMode) {
    yourGridAdapter.setSelectionMode(false);
    yourGridAdapter.clearAllCheckedItems();
    yourGridAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

and in your grid's adapter add following:

```
public void setSelectionMode(boolean selectionOn ){
    this.selectionOn = selectionOn ;
}

public void clearAllCheckedItems() {
    for(YourItemType item: yourItemsList) {
        item.setChecked(false);
     }
}
```

in `getView()`add this:

`convertView.setBackground(yourItemTypeInstance.isChecked() &&  selectionOn ? 
      yourDrawableIndicatingThatItemIsChecked : yourDefaultListItemDrawableIndicator )`

Comment: Thanks, that's good but my issue is that my whole gallery reloads when the CAB gets drawn or removed which also removes the background. But there's no call to ImageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged() or anything alike.

Comment: @m02ph3u5 You have `onCreateActionMode()` and `onDestroyActionMode()` so you can call `notifyDataSetChanged()` yourself.
Maybe you should experiment with another image loading library - `Picasso`

Comment: I don't want to call `notifyDataSetChanged()` - it seems like it's called because all images reload. All I want is to A) keep all images from reloading when cab appers and B) to keep the selection indicator.

Comment: @m02ph3u5 It seems that when CAB appears it causes layout to refresh. You can: A) position your grid view for instance below CAB. So when it appears - layout won't rebuild.
B) Tell your action bar to be overlaying your view - not appearing above. Add this in your theme:
`<item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>`
   `<item name="windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>`
C) Check if caching is possible for your images.